# scala pattern mathing. What is this matching now

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

```
/**
(**) Pack consecutive duplicates of list elements into sublists.
If a list contains repeated elements they should be placed in separate sublists.
Example:

scala> pack(List('a, 'a, 'a, 'a, 'b, 'c, 'c, 'a, 'a, 'd, 'e, 'e, 'e, 'e))
res0: List[List[Symbol]] = List(List('a, 'a, 'a, 'a), List('b), List('c, 'c), List('a, 'a), List('d), List('e, 'e, 'e, 'e))
  */
```

For normal case like this:

```
object MatchTest1 extends Application {
  def matchTest(x: Int): String = x match {
    case 1 => "one"
    case 2 => "two"
    case _ => "many"
  }
  println(matchTest(3))
}
```

I know it's tryhing to match `x` with patterns.

But example as below, what is it matching?

```
// 1- My solution
    /**
     * Similar solution to recusive P08 solution
     */
    def pack(input: List[Any]): List[List[Any]] = {
      def comp(l: List[Any], lastElem: Any, lastList: List[Any]): List[List[Any]] = {
        l match {
          case Nil => List[List[Any]](lastList)
          case head :: tail if head == lastElem => comp(tail, head, head :: lastList)
          case head :: tail if lastList == Nil => comp(tail, head, head :: Nil)
          case head :: tail => lastList :: comp(tail, head, head :: Nil)
        }
      }
      comp(input, Nil, Nil)
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: Recent thread on the feature: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scala-user/I1kNxYFTG4w/7f5V1IdDDtwJ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It checks the `List[Any] l` for the following:

```
// Is it an empty list?
case Nil => ...

// Is it not empty and does the first item (the head) equal `lastElem`?
case head :: tail if head == lastElem => ...

// Is it not emptybut lastList is empty?
case head :: tail if lastList == Nil => ...

// Every other case
case head :: tail => ...
```

Generally `head :: tail` matches if the list has a **head** (the first item) and a **tail** (the rest of the list). The **head** must be an item, **tail** can be an empty list. This means both `[1]` and `[1, 2]` would match `head :: tail`, whereas [] would match `Nil` only.

Comment: Also, "head" and "tail" are just identifiers. `x::y` would work just as well. (`[1]` isn't a list, nor is `[1,2]`, btw)

Comment: @Paul True. Confusing languages. Make that List(1,2) and List(1).